# Привязка команды к MenuItem в CompositeCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Использую контекстное меню для изменения строк `DataGrid`. Каждый пункт меню представляет собой цвет, который применяется к строкам таблицы. 
В коллекции `Colors` сами цвета. Пользователь может удалять или добавлять свои.

Вынес прозрачный цвет из коллекции, чтобы пользователь не мог его удалить и этот пункт был доступен всегда.

Проблема с привязкой пункта меню "Без цвета". 
Команда привязывается, а вот параметр команды, который содержит строки таблицы, которые нужно перекрасить, не привязывается. Хотя в `ItemContainerStyle` параметр команды привязывается тем же способом и все остальное работает как надо. Но вот с пунктом "Без цвета" такой способ, почему-то, не работает.

В чем проблема?

```
<DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    <MenuItem Header="Цвет">
        <MenuItem.ItemsSource>
            <CompositeCollection>
                <MenuItem Header="Без цвета" 
                          Command="{Binding ResultsVM.ResetColorCommand}"
                          CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItems}"/>
                <Separator />
                <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource Colors}}" />
                <Separator />
                <MenuItem Header="Редактировать метки" Click="miColorEdit_Click" />
            </CompositeCollection>
        </MenuItem.ItemsSource>
        <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding ChangeColorCommand}" />
                <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItems}" />
            </Style>
        </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
    </MenuItem> 
</DataGrid.ContextMenu>
```

#### UPDATE

```
<DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu x:Name="ContextMenu">
        <MenuItem Header="Цвет">
            <MenuItem.ItemsSource>
                <CompositeCollection>
                    <MenuItem Header="Без цвета" 
                              Command="{Binding ResultsVM.ResetColorCommand}"
                              CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ContextMenu, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItems}" />
                    <Separator />
                    <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource Colors}}" />
                    <Separator />
                    <MenuItem Header="Редактировать метки" Click="miColorEdit_Click" />
                </CompositeCollection>
            </MenuItem.ItemsSource>
        </MenuItem> 
    </ContextMenu>  
<DataGrid.ContextMenu>
```

#### UPDATE 2

ColorVM:

```
public class ColorVM : BaseVM
{
    private string _title;
    private string _value;

    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set
        {
            _title = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        } 

    } 
    public string Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            _value = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }

    }
    public ICommand ChangeColorCommand { get; set; }
}
```

Коллекция:

```
public static ObservableCollection<ColorVM> Colors { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ColorVM>()
{
    new ColorVM {Title = "White", Value = "#ffffff"},
    new ColorVM {Title = "Black", Value = "#000000"},
    new ColorVM {Title = "Transparent", Value = "#00ffffff},
    new ColorVM {Title = "Yellow", Value = "#ffff00"}
};
```

xaml:

```
<CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Colors}" x:Key="Colors"/>
```

Comment: Попробуйте использовать {Binding ElementName=contextMenu} вместо RelativeSource

Comment: @S.Kost, Это тоже не помогает.

Comment: Хм, странно, через имя должно было было бы работать.

Comment: @VladD, Дополнил ответ кодом с `ElementName`. Может я что-то не так делаю?

Comment: Хм. Должно вроде работать. Попробую воспроизвести.

Comment: @VladD, Вам удалось воспроизвести?

Comment: @maxwell: Нет, сегодня весь день по уши в работе :-\

Comment: @maxwell: Окей, а как выглядит `Colors`? (Который `StaticResource`.)

Comment: @VladD, Это `CollectionViewSource`. Дополнил ответ.

Comment: @maxwell: Ага, понял, воспроизвёл, и даже знаю в чём проблема. Думаю о том, как бы это поправильнее решить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрите, у вас сложная проблема. Дело в том, что имена и `DataContext` наследуются через границу элементов, но не через любую.

У вас есть две точки, которые разрывают это наследование. Первая — `ContextMenu`: оно не является дочерним элементом `DataGrid` (т. к. отображается не вложенным, а как новое окно). Вторая — `CompositeCollection`, которая вообще не является `DependencyObject`'ом, и поэтому не участвует в механизме передачи имён и `DataContext`'а.

В вашем коде есть подход к решению первой части проблемы (`ContextMenu`): использование `PlacementTarget`, но не второй части. Я покажу приём, который изобретён для таких случаев (автор, кажется, Josh Smith). Этот приём известен как Freezable trick.

Мы воспользуемся тем, что классы, наследующие `Freezable`, принимают участие в наследовании `DataContext`'а. Если положить экземпляр такого класса в ресурсы, то в него можно будет положить нужную информацию, а к нему можно будет привязаться через `StaticResource` откуда угодно, даже из места, которое не наследует контексты.

Приступим. Для начала класс:

```cs
public class BindingProxy : Freezable
{
    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore() => new BindingProxy();

    public object Data
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(object), typeof(BindingProxy));
}
```

Теперь его можно использовать так:

```xaml
<DataGrid Name="MyDataGrid">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <local:BindingProxy x:Key="DGProxy" Data="{Binding ElementName=MyDataGrid}"/>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Цвет">
                <MenuItem.ItemsSource>
                    <CompositeCollection x:Name="MyCollection">
                        <MenuItem Header="Без цвета" 
                                  Command="{Binding ResultsVM.ResetColorCommand}"
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding Source={StaticResource DGProxy},
                                                             Path=Data.Content}" />
                        <Separator />
                        <!-- остальная часть меню -->
                    </CompositeCollection>
                </MenuItem.ItemsSource>
            </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    <!-- остальная часть DataGrid -->
</DataGrid>
```

---

Вы можете также положить в `BindingProxy` `ContextMenu`:

```xaml
<ContextMenu Name="MyCM">
    <ContextMenu.Resources>
        <local:BindingProxy x:Key="ContextMenuProxy" Data="{Binding ElementName=MyCM}"/>
    </ContextMenu.Resources>
```

и привязаться к нему:

```xaml
CommandParameter="{Binding Source={StaticResource ContextMenuProxy},
                           Path=Data.PlacementTarget.Content}"
```

Но это не сработает, потому что *имя* `MyCM` не будет доступно внутри `ContextMenu` (не забывайте, что имена не проходят через границы!). Чтобы это сработало, нужно в code-behind (лучше всего в конструкторе, сразу после `InitializeComponent()`) «подшить» область имён `ContextMenu` к внешней части:

```cs
NameScope.SetNameScope(MyCM, NameScope.GetNameScope(this));
```

После этого работает и так тоже.

---

Подробное описание Freezable trick здесь:

- [[WPF] How to bind to data when the DataContext is not inherited](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/)
- [Artificial Inheritance Contexts in WPF](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27432/Artificial-Inheritance-Contexts-in-WPF)
- [Leveraging Freezables to Provide an Inheritance Context for Bindings](http://drwpf.com/blog/2008/05/22/leveraging-freezables-to-provide-an-inheritance-context-for-bindings/)

Comment: Магия :) Огромное спасибо!

Comment: @maxwell: Хорошая магия, забирайте в свой арсенал :)

Answer (score 2):

Добавлю к ответу @VladD еще один способ преодолеть разрыв в наследовании `DataContext`, [подсмотренный тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22074985/6641468):

```
<FrameworkElement x:Name="dummyElement" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Test"
                            Binding="{Binding Name}"
                            Visibility="{Binding DataContext.IsEnable,
                                      Source={x:Reference dummyElement}}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Ого, ещё одно заклинание, спасибо! Кстати, по идее, `FrameworkElement` не должен быть нужен, можно повесить имя просто на `DataGrid`.

Comment: Как оказалсь, подвесить на `DataGrid` нельзя. (Да, прошло больше пяти лет.)