# C# WPF MVVM ContextMenu для TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview, contextmenu

У меня имеется TreeView, у него есть несколько корневых узлов, в каждом из которых содержатся дочерние. Я хочу добавить возможность добавления дочернего узла в корневой узел "Избранное" (изначально этого узла нет, он появляется только в том случае, если в него что-то пожелали добавить). И, конечно, узел "Избранное" -- это часть исходного TreeView. Добавление узлов происходит через контекстное меню (строго один пункт), удаление тоже должно осуществляться через контекстное меню (заменяет пункт с добавлением, если узел уже добавлен), но вот тут начинаются шишки. В интернете есть несколько решений данной задачи:

1. Добавить в ресурсы разное контекстное меню, разделить дерево на несколько деревьев, ставить их друг за другом и указывать соответствующее меню для каждого раздела.
   Это, возможно, решает мою задачу, но дерево бы делить не хотелось.
2. Использовать интерактивность.
3. Заполнять меню для узлов в xaml.cs, но этот вариант точно мне не подойдёт.

Но это всё не совсем то, что мне нужно. Неужели нет чистого способа без нарушения MVVM, дробления исходного дерева и подключения пакетов, который позволит сделать неоднородное контекстное меню для TreeView?

Update: [image: Зарисовка, как это должно выглядеть.]

Comment: Вы можете задать в данных свойство HasChildren например. И если оно false, то через дататриггер задать для корня Visibility.Collapsed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня работает вот как.

Для начала, нам нужен класс для одного элемента. Я взял тривиальный класс, а у вас будет, конечно, что-то посложнее.

```cs
public class ItemVM
{
    public ItemVM(int number) => Number = number;
    public int Number { get; }
    public override string ToString() => $"Item #{Number}";
}
```

Затем, нам нужен класс-контейнер с `ObservableCollection` для «избранного» и «прочего». Дополнительно, нам нужны команды для добавления/удаления элемента из «избранного». Получается что-то такое:

```cs
public class MainVM
{
    public MainVM(IEnumerable<ItemVM> allItems)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(allItems);
        AllItems = new(allItems);
        Favorites = new();
        RestItems = new(AllItems); // use materialized view
        addFavorite = new(OnAddFavorite);
        removeFavorite = new(OnRemoveFavorite);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ItemVM> AllItems { get; }  // всё
    public ObservableCollection<ItemVM> Favorites { get; } // избранное
    public ObservableCollection<ItemVM> RestItems { get; } // остальное

    TrivialCommand<ItemVM> addFavorite, removeFavorite;

    public ICommand AddFavoriteCommand => addFavorite;
    public ICommand RemoveFavoriteCommand => removeFavorite;

    void OnAddFavorite(ItemVM item)
    {
        // перекладываем из "остального" в "избранное"
        Favorites.Add(item);
        RestItems.Remove(item);
    }

    void OnRemoveFavorite(ItemVM item)
    {
        // перекладываем из "избранного" в "остальное"
        RestItems.Add(item);
        Favorites.Remove(item);
    }
}
```

Дальше, XAML. Положим в `TreeView` три элемента: для полного списка, фаворитов и всего прочего. Видимость привяжем к размеру соответствующего списка через конвертер (воспользуемся тем, что изменения `Count` динамически «ловятся» через привязку).

Для разных частей списка положим разные контекстные меню, привяжем их через стиль `TreeViewItem`'а. Чтобы не повторяться, добавим стили в ресурсы.

Поскольку команды определены на внешнем уровне, а на внутреннем прямого доступа к внешнему `DataContext`'у нет, привяжем команду через `DataContext` фиктивного элемента.

```xaml
<Grid>
    <FrameworkElement Visibility="Hidden" x:Name="dummy"/>
    <TreeView>
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem" x:Key="AddFavStyle">
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="Добавить в избранное"
                                      Command="{Binding DataContext.AddFavoriteCommand, Source={x:Reference dummy}}"
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem" x:Key="RemoveFavStyle">
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="Удалить из избранного"
                                      Command="{Binding DataContext.RemoveFavoriteCommand, Source={x:Reference dummy}}"
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.Resources>
        <TreeViewItem
            Header="Избранное" IsExpanded="True"
            Visibility="{Binding Favorites.Count, Converter={StaticResource NonzeroToVisibilityConverter}}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Favorites}"
            ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource RemoveFavStyle}"/>
        <TreeViewItem
            Header="Прочее" IsExpanded="True"
            Visibility="{Binding RestItems.Count, Converter={StaticResource NonzeroToVisibilityConverter}}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding RestItems}"
            ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource AddFavStyle}"/>
        <TreeViewItem
            Header="Всё" IsExpanded="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding AllItems}"
            ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource AddFavStyle}"/>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

Если нужно, реализация `TrivialCommand`:

```cs
public class TrivialCommand<T> : ICommand
{
    public TrivialCommand(Action<T> execute) =>
        executeImpl = execute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));

    public bool CanExecute(object? parameter) => true;

    public void Execute(object? parameter) =>
        executeImpl((T)(parameter ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(parameter))));

    readonly Action<T> executeImpl;

    public event EventHandler? CanExecuteChanged;
}
```

Ну и `NonzeroToVisibilityConverter`:

```cs
public class NonzeroToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) =>
        value is IConvertible conv && conv.ToInt64(null) != 0 ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) =>
        throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

Получается что-то такое:

[image: без анимашки не катит]

Comment: Здравствуйте. Благодарю Вас за ответ. Откровенно говоря, не уверен, что это решает мою проблему, однако трюк с "dummy" выглядит здорово, возьму себе на заметку.

Comment: @Георгий: А можно нарисовать скетч того, как должно выглядеть в идеале? Вероятно, я не совсем понял вопрос.

Comment: Да, конечно, я дополнил вопрос скриншотами (склеил два в одну картинку для удобства), где провернул желаемое через явное указание во View количества узлов и их меню. Только в реальном проекте у дерева может быть сколь угодно узлов, помимо избранного. :)
Кстати говоря, у меня уже появилось потенциальное решение: я делаю один MenuItem для шаблона иерархии, привязываю его Header к новому свойству CommandName (возвращает "удалить из избранного" или "добавить в избранное") и задаю команду. Команда в зависимости от состояния CommandName вызывает уже соответствующий метод: удаления или добавления.

Comment: @Георгий: Обновил ответ

Comment: Внимательно следил за каждым изменением и хочу сказать, что искренне восхищён. Помимо того, что это решает мою задачу, это ещё и наглядно показывает работу с Converter'ами, которые я ранее старательно обходил стороной. Спасибо, что потратили столько времени на это. Уверен, такое решение мне более чем подойдёт.

Comment: @Георгий: Рад, что помогло! Конвертеры вообще очень мощная штука при использовании MVVM, обязательно освойте их.

Comment: Не знаю, поздно ли я с этим вопросом, но всё равно попробую спросить. Если мы хотим получить доступ к внешней VM и создаём для этого невидимый, но участвующий в компиляции Grid, то нельзя ли немного обойти это и наш "dummy" перекинуть сразу на само дерево? Ведь у них одна и та же VM.

Comment: @Георгий: Да, конечно, расположение фиктивного элемента можно менять, ведь вам от него нужен только `DataContext`. Если я не ошибаюсь, есть некоторые ограничения. Фиктивный элемент должен быть определён раньше, чем будет использоваться в `x:Reference` (т. к. парсер XAML однопроходный). И ещё, кажется, он не может быть определён в родительском элементе того элемента, который использует `x:Reference`.

Comment: Кстати, [вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/637858/10105) описан ещё один подход.

Comment: В качестве оффтопа отмечу, что почему-то никак не удаётся привязать Ваш никнейм через собаку. Магия какая-то, но, быть может, только я этого обращения не вижу. :) По поводу порядка определения -- это весьма любопытно. И спасибо за ссылку -- там описано то, о чём я уже находил пару раз информацию, пока искал решение своей проблемы (и не задал вопрос здесь), но не смог толком разобраться.

Comment: @Георгий: Это не баг, это фича (c). Автор сообщения, к которому делается комментарий, в любом случае получает оповещение, поэтому обращение через собаку убирает парсер.

Comment: @Георгий: поменял `Grid` на `FrameworkElement`, так выходит чуть-чуть дешевле.

Comment: Ещё раз спасибо, что уделяете этому время.